# Sample Code and Environment Setup for JMS

Tags: java, jms

How does one install JMS on a desktop setting for learning purposes?

Comment: For example, you can install `GlassFish` server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

JMS is a specification that is implemented by multiple vendors. You need to pick a JMS implementation first. JMS implementations can be bundled with an JavaEE application server such as GlassFish or Jboss, or they can also be found standalone like with [ActiveMQ](http://activemq.apache.org/) and [HornetQ](http://www.jboss.org/hornetq).

For the purposes of experimenting, I'd recommend using a standalone JMS provider as you can use them in regular Java SE applications.

Answer (score 1):

Either install a Java EE Server (GlassFish, JBoss, TomEE), or practice though a Java SE [LinkedBlockingQueue](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/LinkedBlockingQueue.html) instead of JMS